# Tomar solo un Registro por día

Tags: sql-server, date, sql

Buen día, estoy bloqueado y no se me ocurre como solucionar este detalle, tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select a.Cliente,
       b.Nombre'Nombre Cliente',
       a.Agente,
       c.Nombre'Nombre Agente', 
       Count (a.Cliente)'Facturas' 
       from venta  a
       left join Cte b on a.Cliente=b.Cliente
       left join Agente c on a.Agente=c.Agente
       where mov like 'Factura%' 
             and a.Estatus='Concluido' 
             and b.Alta>getdate()-90 
            --and a.Cliente in (select Cliente from cte where alta >getdate()-90)
       Group By a.Cliente,a.Agente,b.Nombre,c.Nombre
       Having Count (a.Cliente)>2
```

Que me arroja el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo el registro 16 me marca que tiene 5 facturas, y es correcto eso, pero en ese caso el cliente tiene 1 factura el 25 de septiembre, otra el 19 de septiembre y 3 el 12 de septiembre, quisiera que solo me tome en cuenta 1 factura por día, por lo tanto que me arroje un 3 en lugar del 5 en mi consulta, el campo de la fecha no se muestra en la consulta pero se llama FechaEmision y es de la tabla Venta.

Espero alguien me pueda apoyar con una manera de realizar lo que quiero.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Prueba con `Count (distinct b.Alta)`

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es obtener el `Count` de facturas de un día específico debes añadirlo en la consulta y en el `GROUP BY`. Debería ser algo así (adaptando la columna de la fecha a lo que corresponda en tu bd):

```
select a.Cliente,b.Nombre'Nombre Cliente',a.Agente,c.Nombre'Nombre Agente', Count (a.Cliente)'Facturas', a.[CAMPO_FECHA] from venta  a
left join Cte b on a.Cliente=b.Cliente
left join Agente c on a.Agente=c.Agente
where mov like 'Factura%' and a.Estatus='Concluido' and b.Alta>getdate()-90 --and a.Cliente in (select Cliente from cte where alta >getdate()-90)
Group By a.Cliente,a.Agente,b.Nombre,c.Nombre, a.[CAMPO_FECHA]
Having Count (a.Cliente)>2
```

Comment: Pero al agruparlo por el dia traerá mas de un registro del mismo, y entiendo que el lo que desea es que donde se ve ese 5 sea 3 por lo que dice que hay dos días en lo que solo se hizo 1 y en el otro día se hizo 3 facturas en un día

Comment: Así es, si le agrego el campo de la FechaEmision solo me arroja los días en los que tiene mas de 2 facturas, lo que quiero es lo que comenta Edgar Vazquez, que solo tome en cuenta una Factura por día, por ejemplo si el día 1 tuvo 10 facturas, el día 2 100 y el día 3 80 me marque que tuvo 3 Facturas( o días de venta)

Comment: Podrias probarlo haciendo un nuevo SELECT sobre la consulta de @Marc quitandole el HAVING y contando la cantidad de registros que obtiene la misma y ya deberia de salirte lo que buscas.

Comment: Muchas gracias! no se me había ocurrido, ya pude hacer la consulta

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos los que Respondieron!
Como me lo sugirió Lucas, me base en la Respuesta de Marc para hacer mi consulta, la cual quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
select Cliente,[Nombre Cliente],Agente,[Nombre 
Agente],Count(Facturas)'Facturas' from (select 
a.Cliente,b.Nombre'Nombre Cliente',a.Agente,c.Nombre'Nombre 
Agente', Count (a.Cliente)'Facturas', a.FechaEmision from 
venta  a
left join Cte b on a.Cliente=b.Cliente
left join Agente c on a.Agente=c.Agente
where mov like 'Factura%' and a.Estatus='Concluido' and 
b.Alta>getdate()-90 
Group By a.Cliente,a.Agente,b.Nombre,c.Nombre, 
a.FechaEmision) tmp
Group By Cliente,[Nombre Cliente],Agente,[Nombre Agente]
Having Count (Cliente)>2
```